# Display/skip to comments that mention me in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to show only (or skip to) the comments that mention me in a collaborative Word document?  I am working on a large (100+ page) document with about a dozen people.  I get an email every time someone mentions me in a comment, but clicking the link in the email simply opens a new copy of the document in my web browser (annoying).  I don't see any way to skip to comments that mention me, in either the desktop or browser app.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Desktop App, the ordinary search in the Navigation pane will find text in comments, including the author's name.

Ctrl+F to get to the search box and type your name.

Comment: Fairly obvious when you think about it.  Thank you.

Comment: I had to try it before I posted this because on my computer, comments are not even displayed. It still found them! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complicate stuff, you can press F5 to open the Find and Replace dialog box. There you can enter a specific reviewer's name.

Answer (score 0):

In my 365, a plain Find does not find anything in the comments. Advanced Find does, but not the person's name -- only the content that person typed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score 0):

In the online version of the Word document (Microsoft 365), which is often pointed to when you get an email about a comment that mentions you,  you cannot search within comments (e.g., to find the comment that mentions you).  To search text in comments, you need to open the Desktop version of the Word. To do that, click on "Reviewing", then "Open in Desktop App". Once within the Desktop app, you can search text everywhere (including the comments) by "Ctrl + F".